# elastic search count don't add up after using aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have an ES index, and I want to count the number of distinct CONTACT ID where [Have Agreement] flag is Y and N. The flag is unique for each CONTACT. However, when I add the contact with Y flag and N flag , the total count is different from total CONTACT number.

1.Total distinct CONTACT_ID count:

```
POST /dashboard/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "CREATED": {
              "gte": "2021-07-04T00:00:00.001Z",
              "lte": "2021-12-31T00:00:00.001Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "UniqueContact": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "CONTACT_ID.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result is 27588

[image]

2.Distinct CONTACT_ID count for Y and N flags respectively:

```
POST /dashboard/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "CREATED": {
              "gte": "2021-07-04T00:00:00.001Z",
              "lte": "2021-12-31T00:00:00.001Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },"aggs": {
    "CVID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Have Agreement.keyword",
        "order": {
          "type_count": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "type_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "CONTACT_ID.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result is 2692 and 2158. They add up  to  4850.
[image]

3. Evidence that shows the flag is unique for each contact

   POST /dashboard/_search?size=0
   {
   "query": {
   "bool": {
   "must": [
   {
   "range": {
   "CREATED": {
   "gte": "2021-07-04T00:00:00.001Z",
   "lte": "2021-12-31T00:00:00.001Z"
   }
   }
   }
   ]
   }
   },"aggs": {
   "CVID": {
   "terms": {
   "field": "CONTACT_ID.keyword",
   "order": {
   "type_count": "desc"
   }
   },
   "aggs": {
   "type_count": {
   "cardinality": {
   "field": "Have Agreement.keyword"
   }
   }
   }
   }
   }
   }

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results seems to be coherent, according to your example.

Keep in mind cardinality are an approximation (you can set it to win some precision)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html

1. You have around 27588 distinct uniqueContact matching your query (cardinality is around 5% precision)
2. Top aggregation by Y or N (Have Agreement.keyword)

In the result we can read:

```
16725 documents with N
11190 documents with Y
```

- For the N group, you have around 2692 different uniqueContact
- For the Y group, you have around 2158 different uniqueContact

So you have "duplicate" matching documents, we can see this in your 3) part.

- 10 doc with 3-QV3ZBW uniqueContact
- 10 doc with 3-QV3ZC3 uniqueContact

=>
So your second request is correct, you have around 2692 distinct uniqueContact with N value (2158 for Y)

The 2692 uniqueContact are present in 16725 docs, the 2158 others refers to 11190

16725 + 11190 => in the 27588 -+ 5%

PS: Add a query term on 3-QV3ZBW for example, I think this will answer to your question with a simple example.

Comment: Thanks. I added precision to be max (40000), and result is coherent now. My data is way above that number if I remove filter though, so looks like I dont have other options here? @LeBigCat